# Obtendo palavras inteiras com RegExp em Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```js
$.fn.wrapInTag = function(opts) {

    var tag = opts.tag || 'strong',
        words = opts.words || [],
        regex = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi'),
        replacement = '<' + tag + '>$&</' + tag + '>';

    return this.html(function() {
        return $(this).text().replace(regex, replacement);
    });
};

$('p').wrapInTag({
    tag: 'em',
    words: ['html', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>O HTML d é muito usado nos dias de hoje, juntamente com o HTML usamos JavaScript e CSS...</p>
```

Estou tendo problemas com o RegExp no Jquery, eu tenho uma lista de palavras que ele pega do <p> e coloca dentro do <em>. Ele funciona quase que certo, porém ele não respeita palavras inteiras, se eu procuro por HTML ele retorna HTML1, HTMLX, HTMLZ e não só HTML, se o HTML está junto com outras palavras ele identifica a palavra também no meio de outras, ele não respeita uma palavra inteira.

O que eu procuro é que:

- "HTML" fique: *HTML*
- "HTMLabc" fique intacto, sem ser itálico, somente: HTMLabc;

Meu código de exemplo: 
http://jsbin.com/zopilefevu/edit?html,js,output

Façam o teste adicionando qualquer letra na frente ou atrás das palavras html, CSS, e JavaScript você poderão ver que ele continua considerando as palavras mesmo tendo outros caracteres juntos no começo ou no final da palavra.

Comment: Funciona para mim... podes explicar melhor como reproduzir o problema?

Comment: Este funciona como queres? https://jsfiddle.net/hrmgwjxf/ (é igual ao teu jsBin)

Comment: Olá boa noite, é assim no texto tem as palavras HTML, CSS e JS. Se você colocar um outro caractere na frente do HTML por exemplo abcHTML, ele continua considerando o HTML eu gostaria que ele respeitasse as palavras já que HTML é diferente de abcHTML.

Comment: ah... ok, percebi.

Comment: Existe uma maneira de arrumar isso ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes juntar uma regra de negação em cada palavra. Ficaria assim:

```
regex = RegExp('(\\W|^)(' + words.join('|') + ')(\\W|$)', 'gi'),
```

e desse modo ficarias com uma regex assim:

```
/(\W|^)(html|CSS|JavaScript)(\W|$)/gi
```

e depois um passo importante:

```
replacement = '$1<' + tag + '>$2</' + tag + '>$3';
```

que faz com que indexe o que foi capturado dentro de cada um dos grupos de captura `()` e, respetivamente, coloca no sítio certo da nova string que vai ser formada.

Assim, na prática impede que haja match se houver uma *letra* ou *numero* **antes ou depois** da paravra que indicaste.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m4dekxq4/

#### regex: https://regex101.com/r/lEP8DX/2

Comment: Nossa amigo muito obrigado :-) Funciona exatamente como eu queria !!!

Comment: @PatrickALima fiz uma melhoria sugerida pelo [`@bacco`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco), assim permitindo ter uma das palavras chave no inicio ou fim do texto da tag.

Comment: Dei uma olhada nas modificações desde já agradeço, ficaram muito boas, gostei, realmente uma boa ideia do bacco. Eu estou tentando pegar o texto de uma textarea com o $('textarea').val(); e passar esse texto como variável para esta função, mais não estou conseguindo kkkkk. Sou um pouquinho iniciante no assunto. Sem querer abusar muito você poderia me dizer como posso mudar a função atual? Desde já agradeço :-). Eu vou incluir mais algumas palavras e gostaria de usar o ultimo método na linha 12 do jsfiddle que separa elas como se fosse um array mesmo, para ele procurar as palavras.

Comment: @PatrickALima adapta o meu jsFiddle para o código que tens e não funciona. Assim posso ver como estás a fazer e ajudar.

Comment: Olá Sergio bom dia, eu quero obter o texto de uma textarea via o keydown, passar esse texto para uma variável e acionar o RegExp para substituir as palavras em itálico e inserir o texto em uma div para mostrar o resultado, porém não estou conseguindo montar essa parte de passar como variável o texto obtido para o RegExp. Deixei em forma de comentário as dúvidas que eu tenho. Aqui segue meu projeto: 
https://jsfiddle.net/patrickalima98/kqmc9fp7/3/
Desde já agradeço pela ajuda e atenção :-).

Comment: @PatrickALima o que precisas então é de uma versão modificada do que tens, para receber uma string e reponder com html formatado... é isso?

Comment: Olá Sergio boa noite, Isso mesmo eu precisava de uma função para fazer isso. Eu andei pesquisando e quebrando um pouco a cabeça com essa função e descobri que é um objeto que guarda essas palavras kkkkk. Marinheiro de primeira viajem kkkkk. Bom depois de dois dias eu consegui montar a função como eu queria. Vou deixa-la aqui caso alguém precise: https://jsfiddle.net/patrickalima98/1kw7wrnp/3/ Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, atenção e pela excelente resposta :-)